# PHP: simple_html_dom - Find text inside a span with class

Tags: php, html, scrape

Given a HTML like this:

```
(...)
<div class="UserLevel type_2">
    <span class="LevelNum">23</span>
</div>
(...)
```

How to get the **23** as a php var using simple_html_dom given the wanted part is inside the span of class `LevelNum` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try :

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=UserLevel type_2]') as $div);
foreach($div->find('LevelNum') as $element) 
    echo $element->innertext;
```

Answer (score 1):

straight out of Simple HTML DOM documentation, have you tried something like

```
$something = $object->find('span[class=LevelNum]');
```